# Remove internal selected div created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking around but i couldn't find a solution yet.
My code is something like this:

```
$('#addDiv').click( function() {

          var divNum = divNum + 1;
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          var divIdName = 'mydiv';
          newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName+divNum);
          newdiv.className = 'imgDiv';

});

$('#cont-div').on('click', function(e) {

        //REMOVE clicked div

});
```

I have a div named "cont-div" which contains the dynamically created divs. 
Probably the solution is very simple, but I can't find a way to identify the clicked div inside 'cont-div' so I can remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation since the `div`s are created dynamically:

```
$('#cont-div').on('click', 'div', function(e) {

        //REMOVE clicked div
        $(this).remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cont-div div').on('click', function(e) {

    var clickedDiv = e.target;

    if(clickedDiv != e.currentTarget)
    {
        //Remove the clicked div if it is not the parent.
        $(this).remove();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, your code implies you may have **multiple elements with the same ID**. Don't do that, that'll make things harder. Just use the class you have set:

```
$('.imgDiv').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: The point about the `id`s is a good one.  It seems the intent of the code was to generate unique `id`s, though from the code we can see, this may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery remove() to remove the element. Also you will need a delegate for simply handling events on dynamicly inserted elements.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xb256/)

**Html:**

```
<input id="addDiv" type="button" value="click!" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.imgDiv',function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Shortened down code snippet, now only showing relevant parts.